# Difficulty with getting rollback to work in python3 with sqlite, pandas, and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using `sqlite` with `sqlalchemy` to write a `pandas` `DataFrame` to a database. I am having a hard time understanding how transactions and rollbacks work with this combination. I followed the instructions from sqlalchemy's website regarding [workarounds for sqlite](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/sqlite.html#pysqlite-serializable), but that doesn't seem to help. Consider the code below.

I first create an empty database.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
import pandas as pd

url = r'sqlite:///'
engine = create_engine(url)

@event.listens_for(engine, "connect")
def do_connect(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    # disable pysqlite's emitting of the BEGIN statement entirely.
    # also stops it from emitting COMMIT before any DDL.
    dbapi_connection.isolation_level = None

@event.listens_for(engine, "begin")
def do_begin(conn):
    # emit our own BEGIN
    conn.execute("BEGIN")

pd.read_sql("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master", engine)
```

The output, as expected is.

```
Out[0]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name]
Index: []
```

Now I write a `DataFrame` using `to_sql` method inside a transaction and purposefully raise an exception, and catch it. I expect the following code to rollback whatever `to_sql` did.

```
data = pd.DataFrame()

# Start a transaction so we can roll back in case of issues
connection = engine.connect()
trans = connection.begin_nested()

try:
    # Save data and script
    data.to_sql('data', connection.connection, if_exists='replace')

    raise Exception

    # Commit transaction
    trans.commit()

except Exception as err:
    trans.rollback()

connection.close()
pd.read_sql("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master", engine)
```

However, from the output we can see that the database was not rolled back to when we started the transaction. I was expecting to see the output of this step to be identical to the one above.

```
Out[1]: 
            name
0           data
1  ix_data_index
```

What am I missing, and is there a way to fix this?

Versions:

```
sys.version
Out[13]: '3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:32:42) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]'

pd.__version__
Out[14]: '0.16.2'

sqlalchemy.__version__
Out[15]: '1.0.8'
```

Comment: But your `Out[1]` just means that the table was created, right? The creation of the table will not be in the transaction, thus it will not be included in the rollback. I'd say that if you do `select * from data`  you will get a 0. I don't think it is an issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: `Out[1]` shows that the `data.to_sql()` function was executed. This function which will drop any existing tables with the same name (`'data'` in this case) and recreate a new table named `'data'` with contents corresponding to the `DataFrame` `data`. However, during this process, if I encounter an error, I want to go back to the state before `data.to_sql()` executed, which is where I start my transaction.